# How to customize boxes direction in tcolorbox rasters?

Tags: tcolorbox, tcbraster

I am using a `raster` of `tcolorbox` to make a formula sheet for my exam. The problem is that my native language (Hebrew) is an RTL language. Therefore, I want the boxes to be arranged from right to left. I tried searching online, but couldn't find how to do that.
For example:

```
% In preamble
\newtcolorbox{cheat}[1]{
    colback=black!5!white,
    colframe=black,
    colbacktitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top right={xshift=-2mm, yshift=-2mm},
    title={#1}
}

% In document
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3]

\begin{cheat}{Heating Problem}
    $\frac{dT}{dt} = -k(T-T_o)$ \\
    $ T_o =$ outside temperature
\end{cheat}

\begin{cheat}{Mixing Problem}
    $\frac{dA}{dt} = c_1r_1-\frac{A}{V}r_2$\\
    $V=V_0 +(r_1 - r_2)t$ \\
    $c_1$, solution mixture in \\
    $r_1$, in rate \\
    $r_2$, out rate
\end{cheat}

\end{tcbraster}
```

Imagine these formulas are written from right to left, so it would make more sense for the boxes to be on the right side.

Does anyone know how to configure it to arrange boxes in a right-to-left, top-to-bottom way?

Comment: What is your minimal complete code to process it?

Comment: You should not place empty lines (= `\par`s) between boxes in a raster which should be placed next to each other.

Comment: Better post a compilable example instead of telling what to put into the preamble and what in the document body.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that adding an empty line (a `\par`) between `\tcolorbox`es in a raster leads to a line break. So avoid placing empty lines between boxes to have them positioned next to each other:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster,skins}

\newtcolorbox{cheat}[1]{
    colback=black!5!white,
    colframe=black,
    colbacktitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top right={xshift=-2mm, yshift=-2mm},
    title={#1}
}

\begin{document}

% With line break
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3]

\begin{cheat}{Heating Problem}
    $\frac{dT}{dt} = -k(T-T_o)$ \\
    $ T_o =$ outside temperature
\end{cheat}

\begin{cheat}{Mixing Problem}
    $\frac{dA}{dt} = c_1r_1-\frac{A}{V}r_2$\\
    $V=V_0 +(r_1 - r_2)t$ \\
    $c_1$, solution mixture in \\
    $r_1$, in rate \\
    $r_2$, out rate
\end{cheat}

\end{tcbraster}

% Without line break
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3]
\begin{cheat}{Heating Problem}
    $\frac{dT}{dt} = -k(T-T_o)$ \\
    $ T_o =$ outside temperature
\end{cheat}
\begin{cheat}{Mixing Problem}
    $\frac{dA}{dt} = c_1r_1-\frac{A}{V}r_2$\\
    $V=V_0 +(r_1 - r_2)t$ \\
    $c_1$, solution mixture in \\
    $r_1$, in rate \\
    $r_2$, out rate
\end{cheat}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image]